# Circuits : Simulation vs Real World

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, simulation, pcb-assembly

I'm asking this question to help many others (specially starters) to have a better understanding about differences that may arise between theoretical/simulation results and real world circuit assemblies.

Hopefully, with help of others (your comments and answers) this thread will be a complete guide listing useful tips and rule-of-thumbs to help others simulate more reliably, with results much closer to real world.

Please list your experiences on what you found different between your simulations and your circuit (preferably short advices and tips) and what changes you think resolved the issue?

Circuit diagrams/schematics and description of your circuit intention may help others better.

Examples of answers could be :

- *I found adding a pull up resistor to a mosfet pin was necessary while Kicad/Spice/Altium simulation worked just fine without one.*
- I had to use buffers between 2 chips I²C communication, cause simulations didn't take the real world noise on wires into account.
- I find using 2 different bypass caps in parallel near IC supply was necessary while in simulation, just one (or none) was enough.

Comment: What is your question exactly?This is not a blog site , it is a questions and answer site so unless you have a question don't post something like this. If you want a blog site my top suggestion would be PhysicsForums .

Comment: Hi! Listing experiences is explicitly **not** what this site is about: this site is for specific questions with correct answers. And all these experiences can be subsumed into a single sentence, anyway: as an engineer, it's your job to verify the models of reality you use are appropriate to your use case. Everything that can will go wrong if you don't think about what cases your models need to cover.

Comment: @MissMulan "I'm voting to..." is something that only higher-reputation users can do. Writing a comment that says "I'm voting to" is a bit misleading, as you're not able to vote on closing a question.

Comment: Simulations will not catch all issues unless the simulation is perfect, which is cost prohibitive. You should also build hardware whenever feasible. A breadboard, brassboard, and/or prototype will reduce your risk. A cost/benefit analysis will be different for each situation.

Answer (score 1):

**In theory and reality if you know all the assumptions, there is no difference**.

In practise , there is.

e.g. initial conditions, output impedance , trace inductance, path length, parasitic coupling, Cap ESR,  inductor DCR, load capacitance, EMI ingress and egress , thermal properties, race conditions, tolerance stackup, voltage margins, thermal environment, etc. Fault detection, correction... Cost Reduction opportunities